# Xamarin iOS how to create non reusable UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, xamarin

I'm trying to create quiz answers, but because of the

```
var cell = (CreateMessageNewAnswerCell)TableView.DequeueReusableCell(CreateMessageNewanswerCell.Key);
```

I'm receiving the same box sizes from previous times.
I know that the Dequeue method reuses the cells and therefore the size stays the one before, I've trying to reset the sizes but it gets itself to an unsolvable problem where the cells change places in their sizes(because of the reuse).

And therefore my question is, how do I create cells without reusing them.
I have tried the following code but it didn't work

```
var cell = new CreateMessageNewAnswerCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CreateMessageNewAnswerCell.Key);

cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
cell.SetModel(createMessageSession.AddAnswersModel, indexPath.Row - 1);
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with the size? Why can't you specify size for a specific row at index path in -heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method?

Comment: The problem is basically the fact I can't use auto layout in this scenario, and therefore I need to recreate cells, and not reuse the existing ones.

Comment: you got something wrong, heightForRowAtIndexPath, as well as cells reusability in tableView has nothing to do with auto layout.

Comment: Ok, but still I need to do the resizing inside the cell and not in heightForRowAtIndexPath, which still brings us to my main question, how do I create cells without reusing them?

Comment: Why? why do you need resize inside the cell? Any reason for that?

Comment: Because the cell has dynamic text => resizing each time

Comment: so calculate the text height in the heightForRowAtIndexPath and then just return the value. That is how you do this, that is what this delegate method is for.

Comment: I think you got out of track, read the post's title again, my question is how to create cells without the dequeue process, not how to resize cells..

Comment: yes, but creating the cells without reusability is by default wrong approach of doing UITableView, your reason to do that, was resizing the cell, right? So, as I see you just trying to solve your code problem in a wrong way.

Comment: so beside telling me I'm using the wrong approach, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: there are two ways how you can configure your cell size. First and simplest one is to determine all constraints for your cell and set row height as UITableView.AutomaticDimension, and second one is to calculate height manually in delegate method called heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Pavel I understand what you're saying, but there is no way for me to use auto layout nor heightForRowAtIndexPath
Why? Simply because my cell height is dynamic, meaning it changes in runtime, and the above methods can not resize in runtime, they calculate the size on static sizes, once a call.
To solve this, each cell needs to resize itself, which is what I'm doing, but here the problems begin

Comment: no, I think you maybe not fully understand possibility of those 2 approaches. If you want to change size dynamically in runtime, just determine heightForRowAtIndexPath and reload the cells whenever your data is changed. Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying similar cells in your UITableView then I do not recommned not using cell reuse as it would negatively impact your scrolling performance and increase memory pressure.

To Handle cells of different size in one UITableView, you could use AutoLayout and set your cells height to Automatic Dimensions.

```
TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 200;
TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
```

This will ensure your cells height fit their content dynamically. For more info checkout this [post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells).

If you still do not want to use cell reuse then don't use DequeueReusableCell instead just return a new instance of your cells in the GetCell method.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really help, because you can't use auto layout to cells which are type-able, therefore you need to handle them by yourself.
Anyways, I'm already handling the size in the cell class, I just need to know how to return a new Cell which will work, because the code I tried obviously doesn't work

Comment: Is your cell defined in a Nib file?

Comment: Yes, my cell is a nib(xib)